# Pythonnet exception: "The 'ExeConfigFilename' argument cannot be null"

Tags: python, mono, python.net

Trying to get a Flask application to call some third party .NET code. I am using pythonnet which I have built myself on a Ubuntu 14.04 host. Have tried both develop and master branches.

The app works perfectly fine with the Flask built-in development server which runs by default on localhost:5000.

The issue is when I throw Apache/WSGI into the mix. I could go on if somebody wants, on the details of the WSGI config (which is in fact deployed via Puppet but that's irrelevant) but in the interest of brevity let's say that it's fairly standard. I have setup WSGI apps before. The web app crashes at the point when it tries to use one of the .NET objects, which in turn tries to deserialize some POSTed JSON. The stack trace is below:

```
   ERROR:SdoEngine:Failed to process request body: System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer' threw an exception. ---> System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException: Error Initializing the configuration system. ---> System.ArgumentException: The 'ExeConfigFilename' argument cannot be null.
at System.Configuration.ExeConfigurationHost.CheckFileMap (ConfigurationUserLevel level, System.Configuration.ExeConfigurationFileMap map) <0x401bd900 + 0x00130> in <filename unknown>:0 
at System.Configuration.ExeConfigurationHost.InitForConfiguration (System.String& locationSubPath, System.String& configPath, System.String& locationConfigPath, IInternalConfigRoot root, System.Object[] hostInitConfigurationParams) <0x401bd4d0 + 0x0011c> in <filename unknown>:0 
at System.Configuration.InternalConfigurationSystem.InitForConfiguration (System.String& locationConfigPath, System.String& parentConfigPath, System.String& parentLocationConfigPath) <0x401bd470 + 0x0004d> in <filename unknown>:0 
at System.Configuration.Configuration..ctor (System.Configuration.InternalConfigurationSystem system, System.String locationSubPath) <0x401bd2e0 + 0x0008d> in <filename unknown>:0 
at System.Configuration.InternalConfigurationFactory.Create (System.Type typeConfigHost, System.Object[] hostInitConfigurationParams) <0x401bd060 + 0x0007c> in <filename unknown>:0 
at System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfigurationInternal (ConfigurationUserLevel userLevel, System.Reflection.Assembly calling_assembly, System.String exePath) <0x401bc720 + 0x002b1> in <filename unknown>:0 
at System.Configuration.ClientConfigurationSystem.get_Configuration () <0x401bc5b0 + 0x00049> in <filename unknown>:0 
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at System.Configuration.ClientConfigurationSystem.get_Configuration () <0x401bc5b0 + 0x000c9> in <filename unknown>:0 
at System.Configuration.ClientConfigurationSystem.System.Configuration.Internal.IInternalConfigSystem.GetSection (System.String configKey) <0x401bc530 + 0x0001f> in <filename unknown>:0 
at System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.GetSection (System.String sectionName) <0x401bc3a0 + 0x00037> in <filename unknown>:0 
at System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer..ctor (System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptTypeResolver resolver, Boolean registerConverters) <0x401bbe60 + 0x0006c> in <filename unknown>:0 
at System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer..cctor () <0x401bbde0 + 0x00032> in <filename unknown>:0 
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at StormTestCoreLib.ScreenDefinition.ScreenDef.DeSerialize (System.String serializedObject) <0x401bbae0 + 0x00045> in <filename unknown>:0 
at (wrapper managed-to-native) System.Reflection.MonoMethod:InternalInvoke (System.Reflection.MonoMethod,object,object[],System.Exception&)
at System.Reflection.MonoMethod.Invoke (System.Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, System.Reflection.Binder binder, System.Object[] parameters, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) <0x401b0780 + 0x000b7> in <filename unknown>:0
```

Mono version is 4.2.2 installed as per www.mono-project.com/docs/getting-started/install/linux/. Have also built it from source from the Mono Github repo with the same result. There is a related [bug](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=10468) which was fixed on release [3.8](https://github.com/mono/mono/commit/57f5187ad29a7913f083a659ea77d90eb8bad4d4), a fix which I do have. I know because I have run `nm` on the mono lib and `mono_domain_set_config` is there.

I am new to mono. It does look like a configuration issue. I have compared the development server and WSGI environment variables and there's nothing blaring at me. At this point I'd appreciate any pointers anyone might have.

PD: Had to remove some links. Not enough reputation unfortunately. I hope the question is clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out it is a bug in pythonnet. If I add a call to `mono_domain_set_config` in their `PyNet_Init` the problem goes away.

```
diff --git a/src/monoclr/pynetinit.c b/src/monoclr/pynetinit.c
index eaa1d9c..ed247f2 100644
--- a/src/monoclr/pynetinit.c
+++ b/src/monoclr/pynetinit.c
@@ -31,6 +31,7 @@ PyNet_Args* PyNet_Init(int ext) {
     pn_args->shutdown_name = "Python.Runtime:Shutdown()";

     pn_args->domain = mono_jit_init_version(MONO_DOMAIN, MONO_VERSION);
+    mono_domain_set_config(pn_args->domain, ".", "Python.Runtime.dll.config");
```